# Will this module work in expo or react native?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, expo, thermal-printer

I am new to react native and expo.

This is the module i am looking at: https://github.com/leesiongchan/react-native-esc-pos

I want to build an app that can print using bluetooth thermal printer. I am not sure if i should build it using react native or expo. Please advise me.

Thank you.

Comment: I just tested it. Expo does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Expo has its own limitations and there are even some bugs there too, Its good for quick development as the documentation suggests the same that it is good to get you started with development within minutes without much hustle. In my opinion, React Native CLI is most of the time the best option even if you are new to react native development. Because of the following reasons

1. You will learn a lot as you will get your hands dirty in core react native app development.
2. You won't have to deal with expo limitations
3. You won't have to be dependent on expo tools

Answer (score 1):

Any Library which requires linking or contains native modules will not work with the expo.

The library you mentioned uses many native modules and usually these type of libraries are not supported and that is the reason why they've built their own APIs and Native Components you can [read this](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/using-libraries/),

the developer has not mentioned Expo support anywhere on the docs but still You can open an issue on GitHub and ask the developer if it supports EXPO platform or not, or maybe instead of asking you can try the library yourself and you will find out if its working or not,